# mysql query query

Tags: php, mysql, join

I Know its a silly question but I'm new to php, so any help is useful.

I have two tables, `product` and `payment`:

- Product table has `Id`, `Room_Available`, `price`, ...
- Payment table has `Id`,`Product_Id`,`Total_Room`, ...
- Product table has many records

What I expected is it gives all product records if `Occupied_Room <= Room_Available`, condition fails as Status = 'Y' otherwise Status = 'N'.

- `cms_product.Room_Available` is Total Room Available
- `cms_payment.Total_Room`  is Room Booked

Query is:

```
SELECT SUM(cms_payment.Total_Room) as Occupied_Room,
    `cms_product`.`Room_Available` as Available_Room  
FROM 
(
    `cms_product` 
    LEFT JOIN `cms_payment` on (cms_product.`Id` = cms_payment.`Product_Id`)
)
GROUP BY `cms_product`.`Id` 
HAVING Occupied_Room <= Room_Available
```

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: Please come up with a better, more descriptive question title.

Comment: @rosipov want all product if condition true or not with status with it .

Comment: I've edited your question to make it at least readable, but 1)You talk about the `payment` table fields twice and never `product`, 2)Is that really your query? Because the FROM derived table is strange, 3)You really need a better title, and 4)What's your question?

Comment: Try adding desired output. Even after lc's formatting question is hard to understand.

Comment: @lc. What's strange, the redundant parenthesis?

Comment: @lc. 1st one is product table . thanks for editing . I edit that in question.

Comment: @ypercube It looks like a derived table - `FROM ()` - but there's no SELECT clause or FROM keyword in it

Comment: It looks like adding an actual question would help the StackOverflow readers understand what you are asking.

Comment: Thanks everyone I keep all these thing in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try thsi out: Following tables use some sample data. You may change the status to `y` or `n` :)

[SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1ecf7/6)

```
select product.id, 
case when coalesce(x.sm,0) <= product.total_room then 
'available' else 'unavailable' end status,
product.total_room, coalesce(x.sm,0) as rooms_required
from product 
left join (
select payment.product_id, 
sum(payment.room_required) sm
from payment 
group by payment.product_id)x
on x.product_id = product.id
group by product.id
;


| ID |      STATUS | TOTAL_ROOM | ROOMS_REQUIRED |
--------------------------------------------------
|  1 | unavailable |         10 |             12 |
|  2 |   available |         15 |             15 |
|  3 |   available |          5 |              4 |
|  4 |   available |         10 |              0 |
```

Comment: @user2001057 please take a look and comment :)

Comment: @user2001057 please mark it as answer then, so everyone knows that your question has been answered. =)

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a stab in the dark, but I think you want:

```
SELECT Prod.Id, 
    CASE WHEN COALESCE(SUM(Pay.Total_Room),0) <= Prod.Room_Available THEN 'Y' 
         ELSE 'N'
    END AS Status
FROM cms_product AS Prod
LEFT JOIN cms_payment AS Pay ON Prod.Id = Pay.Product_Id
GROUP BY Prod.Id, Prod.Room_Available
```

This will show you all product id's and a status (`'Y'`=available or fully booked; `'N'`=overbooked).

Comment: Thanks for giving your valuable time and your help .